# What's wrong in this jQuery $.each() code?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

JavaScript

```
 $.each(['#clk','#clk1'], function()
    {
        $(this).click(function () {
            alert("click")
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
   <a href="#" id="clk">click me</a>
   <a href="#" id="clk1">click me</a>
```

No alert box when the link is clicked.
UPDATE:
I have more than 1 id. I have shown only one to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [`String.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString) to get the value of the `String` object.

It´s not clear why you would need an array of selectors but here are two solutions;

Your solution using [`String.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString);

```
// Array of strings to be used as element selectors.
var selectors = ['#element1', '#element2'];

// Using $.each()
$.each(selectors, function() {
    // String.toString() returns the value of the String object.
    var $this = $(this.toString());

    $this.click(function () {
        console.log('Clicked element(1) =', this.id || this); // DEBUG
    });
});
```

Alternative solution using [`String.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString);

```
// Using String.join()
$(selectors.join(',')).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // This is to not follow the link

    // Notice that "this" now referes to the current/clicked element 
    // and not any string value from the "selectors" array.
    console.log('Clicked element(2) =', this.id || this); // DEBUG
});
```

​

See my **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E5bV8/)**.

If you don´t really need the array of selectors I would recommend a simple [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) like this;

```
$('#element1, #element2').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: +1 I was surprised to find that `this` was a `String` object and not a normal string, but you beat me to the answer.

Comment: +1. Nice to explain why it didn't work as it was, but also the `.join()` thing is a nicer alternative (assuming the array is needed for some other reason).

Answer (score 2):

You could further simplify it to:

```
$("#clk").click (function () {
    alert("click");
});
```

Comment: I have to attach events to multiple selectors. I have shown the problem in simplified way.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why are you using a `foreach` construct when iterating over an id? When you are using and id, there is supposed to be EXACTLY ONE element with the given id. So, this should be fine:

```
$("#clk").click(function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

Secondly, each iterates over an array, your array being `#clk`. Just the string, nothing else. All your function gets is two parameters: `0' (the index of the element) and the string`#clk` (the value at that index). The string IS NOT resolved to a JS object.

Comment: Firstly, OP isn't iterating over an id, OP is iterating over an array that happens to contain an id - there are no duplicates. Secondly, when calling the callback function jQuery sets `this` to the value of the current array item wrapped up as an object if it isn't already. So the string IS resoved to a JS object. See the [doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). (The OP's code doesn't work because the string needs to be unwrapped again for use as a selector.)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the cleanest way to solve your problem statement would be:

```
$("a[id^='clk']").click(function () {
        alert("click");
});
```

The `^=` selector would select all anchors whose id starts with 'clk' and bind the click function to all of those. You can read more about this selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: That's pretty nice solution given your id name's follow a patter. Thanks. Though can't +1 yet.

Comment: Using CSS classes seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Stefan: I agree, using css classes would be more appropriate here. The ^= is particularly useful for attributes like name etc.